# roll through a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like:

```
date        waveLength
01/10/2007  21.0831
02/10/2007  21.3513
03/10/2007  21.2866
04/10/2007  21.0683
05/10/2007  21.7731
08/10/2007  22.626
09/10/2007  22.6274
10/10/2007  22.4751
11/10/2007  21.8606
12/10/2007  22.5411
15/10/2007  22.5007
16/10/2007  22.8511
17/10/2007  23.2782
18/10/2007  23.3793
19/10/2007  22.9508
22/10/2007  23.4952
23/10/2007  25.0852
24/10/2007  25.0542
25/10/2007  24.6298
26/10/2007  24.8885
29/10/2007  24.941
30/10/2007  25.1984
```

I would like to create a rolling window which would take say 5 consecutive days starting at the top of the df dataframe with the window: `01/10/2007` to `05/10/2007` and allow me to create a new dataframe with this data sub set, so the new dataframe (named say `subDf`) would initially look like:

```
date        waveLength
    01/10/2007  21.0831
    02/10/2007  21.3513
    03/10/2007  21.2866
    04/10/2007  21.0683
    05/10/2007  21.7731
```

Once I had processed the subset in `subDf`, I would then be able to roll down the `df` dataframe by one day and recreate the `subDf` datframe so it looks like:

```
    02/10/2007  21.3513
    03/10/2007  21.2866
    04/10/2007  21.0683
    05/10/2007  21.7731
    08/10/2007  22.626
```

this continues until I reach the bottom of the `df` dataframe with the last iteration of `subDf` looking like:

```
    24/10/2007  25.0542
    25/10/2007  24.6298
    26/10/2007  24.8885
    29/10/2007  24.941
    30/10/2007  25.1984
```

Do I need to iterate through the index as an integer (0, 1, 2, 3, 4...), or as dates (01/10/2007, 02/10/2007, 03/10/2007....).

Comment: Do you need to perform operations on each subDF like taking the average or the standard deviation? Pandas allows to apply functions on a rolling slice of a dataframe: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing when you say "roll down" the dataframe by one day and "recreating" the subDf. Why not just create your subset df by using `df.iloc[::5]` ? It doesn't sound like you're doing any aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = ['01/10/2007', '02/10/2007', '03/10/2007', '04/10/2007', '05/10/2007', '06/10/2007', '07/10/2007']
wavelengths = np.random.rand(7)
data = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates,"wavelength": wavelengths})

for row_id in range(len(data)-4):
   sub_data = data.loc[row_id:(row_id+4)]
   print(sub_data)
```

Comment: Please add more information and context. What does this code do and how does this answer the user's question? If you're going to make a code-only answer, the code needs to at least be well commented.